# Is there any way Applying many DDL in a transaction with the Impala?

Tags: transactions, ddl, impala

I've using Cloudera Impala 2.8.0 - cdh 5.11.1, and want to apply some DDLs (`alter table set location '...'`) for multiple tables in a transaction (at once).

Is there any way I could do that?

I've been searching for it, but I found just single table transaction for add partition or something.